# How can i read on serial port and how can i use enter event

Tags: c#, forms, serial-port

i am new in C#
and face a two problem
1/ How can i convent this code to serial code by using serial port not a console
2/ How can i Read by buffer

i write this code to read and write data with putty,
i use virtual serial port emulator to communication between code and putty . and i face problem with the read because the read input from user and i have a conditions, the user should enter "ok" just that if he enter anything they code give me error message

```
class ifstat
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type a sentence");
        int x = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i ++)
        {
                string [] index = { "Comm1", "comm2", "comm3" };
                for (int j = 0; j < index.Length;)
                {

                Console.WriteLine(index[j]);
                String userValue = Console.ReadLine();

                if ( userValue.Contains("ok") )
                  {
                    j++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    while (Console.ReadKey().Key  ==  ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(index[j]);
                    }

                  }   
                 i = 5;  
                }
            Console.Write("Press <Enter> to exit... ");
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) ;
         }    
    }
}
```

Comment: "convent this code to serial code by using serial port" sorry Sara but I am confused. Please explain your aim in more detail. What I can see now is that you have a program to communicate with a user. I don't even fully understand what it is supposed to do. What role plays the serial port in all of this? do you have a device that is attached? and you want to write data to it? and read from it? we need more detail

Comment: i will explain more , i write this code to read and write data with putty,
i use virtual serial port emulator to communication between code and putty . and i face problem with the read because the read input from user and i have a conditions, the ueser should enter "ok" jest that if he enter anything they code give me error message

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) sheet for serial line management.

Don't forget to put this at the top of your source:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
```

Comment: when i used ReadLine function the code stopped on this point and can't counties

Comment: Yes, that's why a separate thread is used in the example.

Comment: @Loerinc the code probably stopped, because `ReadLine` expects a new line character at the end of the input. There is no guarantee that the device is sending a `\r\n` at the end. This would also happen in a separate thread.

Comment: [documentation ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) => `Reads up to the NewLine value in the input buffer.`

Comment: @MongZhu You're right. But since I can only guess what Sara wants, I would wait until she gets the basics down. In the meantime, he will figure out a lot of things on his own, but if you don't ask him.